# graph with tikz, math environment in nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, graphs, tikz-graphs

I'm trying to draw a graph which node text should be in a math environment. For instance consider the following :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph{
    A0 -> A1;
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'd the text of `A0` and `A1` to be `\(A^0\)` and `\(A^1\)` (or using `$...$` even if it is a bad practise, at this point I don't really care).

Outside graphs, I have no problem to have such nodes, and I read from tikz doc that graph vertices are just regular nodes, but yet, I don't know how to do what I want.

If that is relevant, I'm using lualatex, because I need the `\usegdlibrary` for the rest of the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

look in manual, page 259:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph {
A0/$A^0$ -> A1/$A^1$;
};
When you wish to use a node\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or longer version:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph {
A0/[as=$A^0$] -> A1/[as=$A^1$];
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was obviously not searching at the right place. I though I'd find it in part IV. (that being said, I don't think we have the same version of the manual, p.159 is section 14.10 in mine, which is drawing sine/cosine)

Comment: ups, correct page number is 259 (corrected now). sorry for typing error

Comment: Yep, got it. It's 265 on my version (3.0.1 CVS version). For the sake of completeness, I just saw it is equivalent to do `A0/[as=$A^0$] ...`.

Comment: i have 3.0.1a . and yes, i will ad your finding (i left out it because i was lazy to write long version ... :-) . now i will add this possibilities to answer.